# How many one-to-one functions are there from 4-byte words to 4-byte words? How many onto functions?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many one-to-one functions are there from 4-byte words to 4-byte words? How many onto
functions?

My attempt:

{{a, b, c, d}, {a, b, d, c}, {a, c, b, d}, {a, c, d, b}, {a, d, b, 
  c}, {a, d, c, b}, {b, a, c, d}, {b, a, d, c}, {b, c, a, d}, {b, c, 
  d, a}, {b, d, a, c}, {b, d, c, a}, {c, a, b, d}, {c, a, d, b}, {c, 
  b, a, d}, {c, b, d, a}, {c, d, a, b}, {c, d, b, a}, {d, a, b, 
  c}, {d, a, c, b}, {d, b, a, c}, {d, b, c, a}, {d, c, a, b}, {d, c, 
  b, a}}

So the answer is 4!. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, 4! is correct

Answer (score 0):

For maps $f:S \rightarrow S$ for finite sets $S$ (in this case the set of $4$-byte words), one-to-one functions, onto functions and permutations all describe the same functions.

There are $2^{4 \times 8}$ distinct $4$-byte words (assuming a [byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte) consists of $8$-bits), so $|S|=2^{32}$.  The number of permutations of $S$ is $|S|!=2^{32}!$.

What you have listed are the permutations $f:\{a,b,c,d\} \rightarrow \{a,b,c,d\}$, of which there are indeed $4!$.

Comment: So just clarifying would the answer be $2^4!$ or $4!$?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret the question, but I would interpret it as the number of permutations from the set of 4-byte words to itself, which is $2^{32}!$.  On the other hand, $4!$ counts permutations of $\{a,b,c,d\}$, not of $4$-byte words.

Comment: I'll made an edit above; it's $4$-*byte* words, not $4$-bit words (so there's more than $2^4$ of them).